# Horizontal scroll bar with right and left arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have searched through the questions, but couldn't find a solution for mine.
If this question is a duplicate, i am sorry in advance :)

I already asked the theme creator for a solution, but he couldn't give me a fix.

My question is as following.

I am using a WordPress Theme called Contrast and now I have created a page like http://contrast.freevision.me/portfolio-page/horizontal-grid-with-scrollbar/

That page has a custom scrollbar and it is scrollable with the mouse and dragging also works. But how can i make it scroll with the left and right arrow keys?

Do i need to use the jQuery.animate function or is there a more simpeler solution?

This is the code i use for adding the right arrow key. I can see in the text 'right pressed' in console, but nothing happens. I tried different classes, but the animate won't trigger. How can i make the scrollbar move a little to the right everytime i press the right arrow?

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e){
if ((e.keyCode || e.which)  == 39)
{console.log('right pressed')}
{ 
jQuery("div#horizontalGridFolioContainer.horizontal-grid-folio-portfolio.div.div.div").animate({ left: "-=10px" })
}
```

});

Comment: have you referred this link http://contrast.freevision.me/help/ 
this is a Contrast theme help link .

Comment: Thx for your reply. Yes i have, but there is nothing about the scrollbar. It's just you can enable it or disable it. There is no enable button or anything for scroll with arrow keys. I  have also asked the creator if he has a fix, but he didn't have any..

Comment: ok np try to us this link http://jsfiddle.net/mattblancarte/stfzy/21/
it's a jquery animation function link.

Comment: I added some code to my post. I tried the animate function, but there is no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but this can be helpful

```
let scroll_length = 40;
/*Scroll left right*/
$(document).on('keydown',function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        element_scroller_wrapper.scrollLeft -= scroll_length;
        console.log('<--')
    }else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        element_scroller_wrapper.scrollLeft += scroll_length;
        console.log('-->')
    }
});
```